# Vscode - Python Debugger: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug some Python code I have which I can run with no problem by typing the following in bash:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 \
python test_multi.py \
--experiment_name 128_shortcut1_inject1_none \
--test_atts Eyeglasses \
--test_ints -1.0
```

I've created this json config file for VScode:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "<absolute_path>/test_multi.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": [{ "name":"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "value":0}],
            "args": ["--experiment_name 128_shortcut1_inject1_none", "--test_atts Eyeglasses", "--test_ints -1"]
        }
    ]
}
```

but I keep getting
`test_multi.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --experiment_name 128_shortcut1_inject1_none --test_atts Eyeglasses --test_ints -1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your use of `args` is slightly off; you need to treat each part of your arguments as their own string when they are to be passed in as individual things. The following should fix it:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "<absolute_path>/test_multi.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": [{ "name":"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "value":0}],
            "args": ["--experiment_name", "128_shortcut1_inject1_none", "--test_atts", "Eyeglasses", "--test_ints", "-1"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The way Brett shows didn't work with my case. I want to use the Number "1" GPU for debugging, so I added
`"env": {"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":"1"},` to the `launcher.json` file.

Comment: I also add multiple variables setting. `env": {"PYTHONPATH":".", "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES": "0"}`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at this thread to see how I could use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` in `env` and the way you wrote it down, here:

```
"env": [{ "name":"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "value":0}]
```

, didn't work for me.
I had to correct it to:

```
"env": {"name":"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "value":"0"}
```

I imagine the `[]`- brackets are only expected when you have more then one entry?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so previous answers didn't work for me (my VSCode version is 1.85.2).
To be more precise

```
"env": {"name":"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "value":"1"}
```

approach was the only one that got past any VSCode errors but still it didn't work (`tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")` listed all of my GPUs).

But this did the trick (when I wanted to use GPU with associated number of 1, but it works the same if I wanted GPU with number 0):

```
"env": {"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES": "1"}
```

Hope it helps!